# how to get text box values from webserver of esp32 and print them in to serial monitor by using <webserver.h> library

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, esp32

Actually I'm trying to get the values from esp32 server webpage. Suppose there is a web page containing some text box fields, user has to enter some details in it and this details I want to be print on serial monitor.

And didn't get any solution regarding that. Though it is working with ESPAsyncWebServer.h library, that i found here -- > https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-esp8266-input-data-html-form/

but I want to do this task with webserver.h library, for some reason I don't want to use ESPAsyncWebServer.h library.. Hope you all guys can understand what I'm trying to ask and say. Thank You.

Comment: Do you, first of all, understand how HTML forms function?

Comment: html side if i try method = post, then how would i fetch this post value in arduino ? in php its so easy to fetch with $_POST["value"], but in arduino i don't have any idea about it. new to arduino programming so facing this problem.

Comment: POST data is just in the body of the request. I don't know how webserver.h will present that to you.

Comment: thats the problem brother, i guess i need to dig more deep into this library.

Comment: see the SimpleAuthentification example

Comment: I didn't get one  @Juraj  .. Still struggling and finding a way to do this task :(

Comment: `$_POST["value"]` is `server.arg("value")`